# Dynamically assign a key value when writing a new data to firebase realtime database using firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a cloud function code to create a record in a collection, I want to assign dynamic value as a sub-collection name to the record am creating. The code is as blow

```
var mobileNumber = eventSnapshot.child('mobileNumber').val()
usersRef.update({
  mobileNumber: {
    email: eventSnapshot.child('email').val(),
    isUserEnabled: eventSnapshot.child('isUserEnabled').val(),
    name: eventSnapshot.child('name').val()
  }
});
```

The record added to the collection

```
mobileNumber: {
 email: "xxxxxx@xxxx.xx",
 isUserEnabled: true,
 name: "YYYYYYYYYY"
}
```

but what I meant to get was a record like the one below

```
+919876543210: {
 email: "xxxxxx@xxxx.xx",
 isUserEnabled: true,
 name: "YYYYYYYYYY"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `child()` to access the key under the usersRef. And then update the value under that key:

```
var mobileNumber = eventSnapshot.child('mobileNumber').val()
usersRef.child(mobileNumber).update({
    email: eventSnapshot.child('email').val(),
    isUserEnabled: eventSnapshot.child('isUserEnabled').val(),
    name: eventSnapshot.child('name').val()
});
```